# Apache Flink 1.16 - DLQ

Tags: apache-flink

I have a usecases for handling the failure recovery and retryable. I have got to know the retryable option in the Flink . But What will happen after the maximum attempt of retryable. Is it move to DLQ ? If So Do we have any documentation for DLQ implementation .

Answer (score 0):

If the maximum amount of retries has been attempted, your job will fail. You will need to update your job so that it properly handles the cause of your failure. For example, if you have a problem with deserializing your incoming data, you could send that data to a dead letter queue topic on Apache Kafka.

An example of this can be found at https://docs.immerok.cloud/docs/cookbook/creating-dead-letter-queues-from-and-to-apache-kafka-with-apache-flink/

Note: I work for Immerok

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Let me try it out

Comment: Hi , Immerok . Can you provide me a  complete examples. Let me say, I have a 3 task in my class and dropping a msg in to another topic through the kafka sink. I wanted to have a examples ,if any exceptions happening , it should retry and if reach maximum attempt then it will redirect to DLQ. Can you please help me on this use case.